How to Transfer a Clonezilla Image to a Smaller SSD?
I have two computers, PC1 and PC2. PC2 has a smaller SSD Drive. PC1 is running Ubuntu 20.04.
I want to create an image of PC1 using Clonezilla and transfer this image to a flash drive. Then, I want to use the image to set up PC2 to run Ubuntu just like PC1.
However, I encountered a problem because PC2 has a smaller SSD drive. When I try to transfer the image, Clonezilla shows an error indicating that the current space is too small.
How can I solve this problem?

Another alternative is just do a new install to PC2 and restore from your normal backup of PC1. Good test that your backups are complete as you still have PC1 to get any missing info. Backup at minimum for a desktop should be /home, list of installed apps and maybe some settings in /etc, but those often are specific to system. And if data partitions those need backup.  I have grub settings in /etc that I do make copies & include a copy in /home. If server apps, you need those from / also. If SSD you can install in 15 minutes. download apps & restore /home. An hours depending on system speeds.

To solve the problem of transferring an image from PC1 to PC2 using Clonezilla when PC2 has a smaller SSD drive, follow these steps:

Shrink the Partition on PC1: Before creating an image with Clonezilla, shrink the partition on PC1 to a size that fits within the smaller SSD on PC2. You can use GParted for this purpose.

Boot PC1 with a GParted live USB.
Open GParted and select the partition you want to shrink.
Resize the partition to a size that will fit on the smaller SSD of PC2.
Apply the changes and reboot PC1 to ensure the system still works correctly.


Create an Image with Clonezilla:

Boot PC1 with a Clonezilla live USB.
Follow the Clonezilla wizard to create an image of the shrunk partition.
Save the image to your flash drive.


Transfer the Image to PC2:

Boot PC2 with the Clonezilla live USB and the flash drive containing the image.
Follow the Clonezilla wizard to restore the image to PC2’s SSD.


Resize Partition on PC2:

Once the image is restored, you may need to resize the partition on PC2 to utilize the full capacity of the smaller SSD. Again, use GParted for this.
Boot PC2 with a GParted live USB.
Resize the restored partition to occupy the entire SSD.
Apply the changes and reboot PC2.




Thanks for answering
